# Possible ways to send nested JSON data to server - extjs 4.2.x

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4.2

I have JOSN data as below.

I am not able to figure out what is the way of sending this data to server in POST method.

In UI, Lets say i have a form where i have one combobox **country** and two multiselect grids **Exhibition**, **Location** and **Fact Details** (JSON store) and one Save button.
when i click on create button, i have to send data in below format. as i have this functionality already created using SOAP and some other UI technology. now i just want to do same using REST JSON and Extjs.

Please suggest me some ways of sending this data to server.

```
{
  "NewStoreReportReq":{
      "countryID":"170",
      "countryName":"COLOMBIA",
       "Exhibitions":[
          {
            "exhibitionID":"1004"
          },
          {
            "exhibitionID":"1007"
          }
        ]
      ,
        "Locations":[
          {
            "locationID":"70"
          }
        ]
      ,
        "FactsDetails":[
          {
            "factID":"22"
          },
          {
            "factID":"23"
          },
          {
            "factID":"24"
          }
        ]

    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you wanting to do this as a Ext.Ajax.request(), as part of a store update, or something else? Sending JSON data as part of a POST is very easy, but we need to know how you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

//here you will construct your complex object getting the data from your grids or any other view

```
var myComplexObject = {
        "NewStoreReportReq": {
            "countryID": "170",
            "countryName": "COLOMBIA",
            "Exhibitions": [
                {
                    "exhibitionID": "1004"
                },
                {
                    "exhibitionID": "1007"
                }
            ],
            "Locations": [
                {
                    "locationID": "70"
                }
            ],
            "FactsDetails": [
                {
                    "factID": "22"
                },
                {
                    "factID": "23"
                },
                {
                    "factID": "24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

//Here you would json encode your object

```
var jsonObject = Ext.encode(myComplexObject);
```

//Here you would perform an Ajax request to the server ...

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '../SomeServlet',
    method: 'POST',          
    params:{
        'jsonObject': jsonObject
    },
    //here you can handle the response of the server
    callback: function (opts,success,response){
         var serverResponse = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
         // the property message has to be returned in json format
         Ext.Msg.alert(serverResponse.message);
        }

});
```

Assuming you are using java and a servlet (yes, yes I know) you would have to receive this object something like `String json = request.getParameter("jsonObject");` and then use a library like Jackson to convert that json to a Java object.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As i have Exhibition, Location data in Grid. can you please tell me how to get this data from grid and create above complex data?

Comment: you need to listen to the itemClick event from a ExtJs controller this event sends the content of the record as you can see here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-itemclick

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define("appWriter", {
  extend: "Ext.data.writer.Json",
  writeRecords: function (request, data) {
    var root = this.root;

    if (this.expandData) {
      data = this.getExpandedData(data);
    }

    if (this.allowSingle && data.length === 1) {
      data = data[0];
    }

    request.jsonData = request.jsonData || {};
    request.jsonData[root] = data;

    return request;
  },
});

Ext.define("Ext.data.Store.proxy.ModifiedAjax", {
  extend: "Ext.data.pro`enter code here`xy.Ajax",
  alias: "proxy.modifiedajax",

  defaultParams: "param",
  removeDefaultParams: true,

  buildRequest: function (operation) {
    var me = this,
      request,
      defaultParams = me.getParams(operation);

    request = new Ext.data.Request({
      params: {},
      action: operation.action,
      records: operation.records,
      operation: operation,
      url: operation.url,
      proxy: me,
      jsonData: defaultParams,
      action: "post",
    });
    request.url = me.buildUrl(request);
    operation.request = request;

    return request;
  },
});

Ext.define("ForumThread", {
  extend: "Ext.data.Model",
  fields: [
    "title",
    "forumtitle",
    "forumid",
    "username",
    { name: "replycount", type: "int" },
    { name: "lastpost", mapping: "lastpost", type: "date", dateFormat: "timestamp" },
    "lastposter",
    "excerpt",
    "threadid",
  ],
  idProperty: "threadid",
});

var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
  pageSize: 50,
  model: "ForumThread",
  remoteSort: true,
  proxy: {
    // load using script tags for cross domain, if the data in on the same domain as
    // this page, an HttpProxy would be better
    type: "modifiedajax",
    url: "http://localhost/api/test.php",
    reader: {
      root: "topics",
      totalProperty: "totalCount",
    },
    writer: Ext.create("appWriter", {
      root: "ignore",
    }),
    // sends single sort as multi parameter
    simpleSortMode: true,
    action: "post",
  },
  sorters: [
    {
      property: "lastpost",
      direction: "DESC",
    },
  ],
});
```